# Error on running 'npm install' to install React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation

I have tried to install React by calling `npm install`, but I have receive the following error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_chdir

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `sudo npm install` it might work

Comment: run `npm cache clean` and try after disabling antivirus.

Comment: Thank you. I did this already but didnt help. But right now I found solution. Hope this can help somebody else. I made installation in xampp -> htdocs and everything is OK :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill your node processes, maybe it works fine after this. You are working on windows I suppose because is a common problem on windows platforms.

Comment: Is there an external ressource supporting your theory?